# Spring RESTful accepting request action

Tags: spring, rest

In Spring RESTful application I have `User`, `Game` and `GameRequest` resources. `User` can join a `Game` by sending a request. So far everything is ok. But how can I achieve that `User` accept a request? I thought about deleting `GameRequest` but then how can I know if `User` accepted or rejected request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

POST some parameter like `accepted=true` to `GameRequest/xyz` to change `accepted` attribute.

Or make `GameRequestAccepted` resource and then

```
PUT /GameRequestAccepted/xyz
```

But this will modify your `GameRequest` anyway (implicitly).